Custom headers in spring sleuth open telemetry
I have 2 microservices A and B. And I have such chain of requests -> A -> B ->.
I want to use opentelemetry (with w3c header traceparent) and I want to propogate a custom header x-trace-id throw my services.
I have spring boot 2.6.3, spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-dependencies 1.1.4
I added such config:
spring:
  sleuth:
    baggage:
      remote-fields:
        - x-trace-id
      tagFields:
        - x-trace-id
      correlation-enabled: true
      correlation-fields: x-trace-id
    propagation:
      type: w3c
    opentracing:
      enabled: true

But I don't see x-trace-id when call A with such header. I don't see in Span, in Context. I don't see in request from A to B.
But if I set in baggage like this
 String hed = request.getHeader("x-trace-id");
baggageManager.createBaggage("x-trace-id", hed);

I see in request from A to B header:
baggage:"x-trace-id=JojaOpen2;propagation%3Dunlimited"
How fix it and propogate header x-trace-id throw my services and how set this header to trace context in services (for logger)?
